# Filer contents of a string array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, loops, indexing, filter

I am writing a code that takes a string array and filters out certain contents that contain a certain letter. For example, for the array that I have, I want to filter out all the contents that contain the letter "b" and remove them out of the array without creating a new array (removes from the existing array). I am currently using the indexOf method and it is giving me problems. It gives me an error saying that int cannot be converted into string. I am not sure what the probelm is with that.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] arr = {"abc","bcd", "cad", "aaa"};

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length(); j++){
            String index = arr[i].indexOf(j, j + 1);
            if(index == "b"){
                arr[i] = "";
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe that you want charAt() rather than indexOf().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr[i].indexOf(j, j + 1)` should be replaced by `arr[i].substring(j, j + 1)` because the return type of `String#indexOf` is an integer, but you're expecting the character back at this position.

and

`if(index == "b")` by `if(index.equals("b"))` because you might get unexpected results due to the fact that `index` and `"b"` are two different objects. That's the reason why `String#equals` should be used

---

That said, there is a more easy way to achieve what you're doing which is more straightforward by using `String#contains`

```java
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] arr = {"abc","bcd", "cad", "aaa"};

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i].contains("b")) {
            arr[i] = "";
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're running into is that the String.indexOf method returns the location in the string where another string occurs or -1 if it does not occur. In your case you're looking through each entry in the array and checking to see if j appears in the string.

If you want to use indexOf you could instead use arr[i].indexOf("b"). This would search through the string for the given substring "b". Then you would have to check the returned value to see if it is not equal to -1 and if it isn't then assign that location of the array to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate solution using Java's Stream API

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String [] arr = {"abc","bcd", "cad", "aaa"};
        arr = Arrays.stream(arr)
                    .filter(str -> !str.contains("b"))  // Remove elements containing "b"
                    .toArray(String[]::new);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose @jhale1805 that you are not modifing an existing array but creating a new one –

Comment: @SergeyAfinogenov you are correct that the OP asked that the solution work "without creating a new array" and this solution technically does create a new array. That said, the OP also requested that a solution "remove [the elements with a 'b'] out of the array". IMO, taking something "out of the array" implies a resize to a smaller capacity which requires creating a new array. In light of the conflicting requirements I chose to prioritize the latter in my solution.

As a side note, your solution that substitutes the empty string using Streams taught me something new! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By using stream of array indexes:

```
   IntStream.rangeClosed(0,arr.length-1)
         .forEach(i -> {if (arr[i].contains("b")) arr[i]="";});
```

or:

```
 IntStream.rangeClosed(0,arr.length-1)
          .filter(i-> arr[i].contains("b"))
          .forEach(i-> arr[i]="");
```